# Should houses be destroyed?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

[houses](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/houses) is a pretty useless tag. Since it's only got two questions to its name, should we edit those to remove it?

Comment: +1 for the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Burninated [houses](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/houses) has been.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the only 2 questions there are for that tag aren't even for the same game, I would think it would be fine to go ahead and nuke them. Out of the two, only Minecraft has enough questions to warrant sub-tagging, and if we only have *one* question tagged with houses for it, I'd say it's safe to remove.